# MahApps Metro NumericUpDown problems

Tags: xaml, mahapps.metro

After using MahApp Metro formy project in WPF I encountered a problem I can't solve. the framework works fine except when I am using the NumericUpDown control. 
I can see this control onto my UserControl while I'am working on it. But at the compilation the code then becomes :

The tag 'NumericUpDown' does not exist in XML namespace "http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls". Line 75 Position 26.

With my XAML code it could perhaps help :

```
<UserControl x:Class="FullTest.Tabs.DataGridStrategie" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"             
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"             
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:FullTest.ModelView.Convertors"            
         xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"            
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:FullTest.UtilityClasses"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">  
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"  MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/emerald.xaml" />           
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                 
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>   
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Str...}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,-172,0" x:Name="MainGrid">

    <DataGrid.Columns>          

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Colors ..." Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Name="superCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}" SelectedItem="{Binding BrushColor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5" Background="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 

        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name of ..." x:Name="Str.." Width="150">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Name="itemNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Typ o....">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Name="TypeStrat" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Typ....}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode= TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>               
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>      


      <!--Here Appears the problem due to the controller-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:NumericUpDown Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Height="23"
                            Margin="5,5,5,5"
                            Interval="1"
                            StringFormat="{}{0:###0}"/>


                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>



    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I could provide more information if it can be useful.

Comment: Do you have the `MahApps.Metro.dll` in your bin folder ?

Comment: Yes I put the .dll into the folder

Comment: I have downloaded the MahApps dll from the  nuget packages and it works fine now. Why is it better than the dll I have taken from the github  https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro ?

Comment: No this shouldnt be the problem - even more if you use `Nuget`. Generally C# / VS handling `Depdendencies` pretty awesome.